# Capitalise first letter in String

Tags: java, stringbuilder, capitalize

I'm having trouble converting the first letter to Capital in a String:

```
rackingSystem.toLowerCase(); // has capitals in every word, so first convert all to lower case
StringBuilder rackingSystemSb = new StringBuilder();
rackingSystemSb.append(rackingSystem);
rackingSystemSb.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(rackingSystemSb.charAt(0))); 
rackingSystem = rackingSystemSb.toString();
```

This doesn't seem to work..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try doing:

```
rackingSystem = rackingSystem.toLowerCase();
```

Instead of:

```
rackingSystem.toLowerCase();
```

Strings are immutable, you must reassign the result of `toLowerCase()`.

Easier though, (as long as your String is larger than length 2):

```
rackingSystem = rackingSystem.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + rackingSystem.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: `public static String capitalize(String s) {
  if(s == null) return null;
  if(s.length() == 1){
   return s.toUpperCase();
  }
  if(s.length() > 1){
   return s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
  }
  return "";
 }`

Answer (score 18):

```
StringBuilder rackingSystemSb = new StringBuilder(rackingSystem.toLowerCase());
rackingSystemSb.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(rackingSystemSb.charAt(0)));
rackingSystem = rackingSystemSb.toString();
```